# Installation of "gdb64" on Trusty removes "ubuntu-minimal", is that right?

Tags: apt, 64-bit, 14.04, gdb

I have a 64-bit Ubuntu Trusty and I'm trying to install the package `gdb64` but, I'm seeing the following packages that are about to be REMOVED, look:

```
sudo apt-get install gdb64
.....
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  devscripts python3-apt python3-chardet python3-dbus python3-debian python3-magic python3-pycurl python3-six python3-software-properties software-properties-common ubuntu-minimal unattended-upgrades
.....
```

Is that right / expected?!

I'm newbie with `gdb`... Can I install `gdb` instead? I'll need to debug a 64-bit binary...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this package is intended for debugging 64 bit programs ( remotely ) on a 32 bit system.  I'm not even sure why it is showing as installable on 64bit, which seems to be a bug.  You want to just install the regular gdb package.

Comment: Mmmm... Okay! Cool... Tks!